# Finding iOS device idle state

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to find the device idle state through program. i.e. find the state when the device is not moved or moved.
I tried the following accelerometer and core motion APIs. But, I couldn't understand the device idle state from the values it is giving.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    currentMaxAccelX = 0;
    currentMaxAccelY = 0;
    currentMaxAccelZ = 0;

    currentMaxRotX = 0;
    currentMaxRotY = 0;
    currentMaxRotZ = 0;

    value = 0;

    self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = .2;
    self.motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = .2;

    [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                             withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData  *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                                                 [self outputAccelertionData:accelerometerData.acceleration];
                                                 if(error){

                                                     NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                 }
                                             }];

    [self.motionManager startGyroUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                    withHandler:^(CMGyroData *gyroData, NSError *error) {
                                        [self outputRotationData:gyroData.rotationRate];
                                    }];
}

-(void)outputAccelertionData:(CMAcceleration)acceleration
{
    self.accX.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"accX: %.2fg",acceleration.x];
    if(fabs(acceleration.x) > fabs(currentMaxAccelX))
    {
        currentMaxAccelX = acceleration.x;
    }

    self.accY.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"accY: %.2fg",acceleration.y];
    if(fabs(acceleration.y) > fabs(currentMaxAccelY))
    {
        currentMaxAccelY = acceleration.y;
    }

    if (fabs(acceleration.y) - fabs(value) > 0.2 || fabs(value) - fabs(acceleration.y) > 0.2 )
    {
        NSLog(@"Not idle");
    }
    value = acceleration.y;


    self.accZ.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"accZ: %.2fg",acceleration.z];
    if(fabs(acceleration.z) > fabs(currentMaxAccelZ))
    {
        currentMaxAccelZ = acceleration.z;
    }

    self.maxAccX.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"maxAccX: %.2f",currentMaxAccelX];
    self.maxAccY.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"maxAccY: %.2f",currentMaxAccelY];
    self.maxAccZ.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"maxAccZ: %.2f",currentMaxAccelZ];

}

-(void)outputRotationData:(CMRotationRate)rotation
{
    self.rotX.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rotX: %.2fr/s",rotation.x];
    if(fabs(rotation.x) > fabs(currentMaxRotX))
    {
        currentMaxRotX = rotation.x;
    }
    self.rotY.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rotY: %.2fr/s",rotation.y];
    if(fabs(rotation.y) > fabs(currentMaxRotY))
    {
        currentMaxRotY = rotation.y;
    }
    self.rotZ.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rotZ: %.2fr/s",rotation.z];
    if(fabs(rotation.z) > fabs(currentMaxRotZ))
    {
        currentMaxRotZ = rotation.z;
    }
    self.maxRotX.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"maxRotX: %.2f",currentMaxRotX];
    self.maxRotY.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"maxRotY: %.2f",currentMaxRotY];
    self.maxRotZ.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"maxRotZ: %.2f",currentMaxRotZ];
}
```

Comment: " I couldn't understand the device idle state from the values it is giving." What values is it giving?

Comment: Can you suggest whether what i'm trying is the right approach or not? Can you please suggest some way to find device idle time on the iOS device?

Comment: If by idle you mean _not moving_... please change the question text to use the word **stationary** _instead of idle_.... for a phone (or electronic devices in general) idle state refers to no running programs (or no digital activity in general) etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can check this reference [CmMotionManager reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/).

```
self.deviceQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 5.0 / 60.0;

// UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];

[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical
                                                    toQueue:self.deviceQueue
                                                withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
{
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    CGFloat x = motion.gravity.x;
    CGFloat y = motion.gravity.y;
    CGFloat z = motion.gravity.z;
}];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach with measuring acceleration is correct, so in case you managed to obtain acceleration vector, you simply should calculate [the norm of the vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) and check if the value is grater than some constant.

```
CGFloat norm = sqrt(acceleration.x * acceleration.x + acceleration.y * acceleration.y + acceleration.z * acceleration.z);
NSLog(@"Norm of the vector = %f", norm);
CGFloat minimumValueToConsiderThatDeviceIsMoving = 0.2; // obtain more accurate value experimentally
if (norm > minimumValueToConsiderThatDeviceIsMoving) {
    NSLog(@"Device is moving!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Device is still!");
}
```